# Trouble copying over 1 column to right each time I run macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA, attempting to copy values from one tab, named `lookup xxx` (the data will always be in `Column F`) and Paste into the associated `actuals xxx` tab.

I do this for about 10 different lookup tabs. My goal is to paste `Week 50`, or `201750` into `Column F`, the first time I run the macro.

The 2nd time I run it, I want to paste into `column G`, and the third time, `column H`, and so on; each time keeping the data in the previous columns.

The built in Macro, or `Personal.xlsb!AllSheets` updates the data on the lookup tab, and updates the weeks. This is really a "copy and paste over one column" question.

**What I want to happen is this:**

- the first time I run it, column F on `actuals xxx` tab is filled with `201750` data (from `lookup xxx` tab)
- The next time I run it, `column F` keeps `201750`, and `G=201751` data.
- The next time I run it,`F=201750, G=201751, H=201752` data
- and so on...

**What actually happens, is:**

- the first time I run it, both `columns F` and `G` on `actuals xxx` are filled with `201750` data.
- The next time I run it, `F=201751, G=201750, and H=201751`.
- The next time I run it, `F=201750, G=201751, H=201752, I=201752.`

**Here is the code I'm currently using:**

```
  Sub ActualsAutomation()
    '
    ' ActualsAutomation Macro
    '

    '
        Application.Run "PERSONAL.XLSB!AllSheets"

        Sheets("SS Actuals").Range("F3:F500").Value = Sheets("SS Lookup").Range("F1:F498").Value

        Dim c As Long

        c = Sheets("SS Actuals").Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
        Sheets("SS Actuals").Cells(3, c).Resize(498).Value = Sheets("SS Lookup").Range("F1:F498").Value

        Sheets("All Actuals").Range("F3:F500").Value = Sheets("All Lookup").Range("F1:F498").Value

        c = Sheets("All Actuals").Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
        Sheets("All Actuals").Cells(3, c).Resize(498).Value = Sheets("All Lookup").Range("F1:F498").Value

        Sheets("Base Specialties Actuals").Range("F3:F500").Value = Sheets("Base Specialties Lookup").Range("F1:F498").Value

        c = Sheets("Base Specialties Actuals").Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
        Sheets("Base Specialties Actuals").Cells(3, c).Resize(498).Value = Sheets("Base Specialties Lookup").Range("F1:F498").Value

        Sheets("Combat Actuals").Range("F3:F500").Value = Sheets("Combat Lookup").Range("F1:F498").Value

        c = Sheets("Combat Actuals").Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
        Sheets("Combat Actuals").Cells(3, c).Resize(498).Value = Sheets("Combat Lookup").Range("F1:F498").Value

        Sheets("Great Value Actuals").Range("F3:F500").Value = Sheets("Great Value Lookup").Range("F1:F498").Value

        c = Sheets("Great Value Actuals").Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
        Sheets("Great Value Actuals").Cells(3, c).Resize(498).Value = Sheets("Great Value Lookup").Range("F1:F498").Value

        Sheets("Persil Actuals").Range("F3:F500").Value = Sheets("Persil Lookup").Range("F1:F498").Value

        c = Sheets("Persil Actuals").Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
        Sheets("Persil Actuals").Cells(3, c).Resize(498).Value = Sheets("Persil Lookup").Range("F1:F498").Value

        Sheets("Purex Actuals").Range("F3:F500").Value = Sheets("Purex Lookup").Range("F1:F498").Value

        c = Sheets("Purex Actuals").Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
        Sheets("Purex Actuals").Cells(3, c).Resize(498).Value = Sheets("Purex Lookup").Range("F1:F498").Value

        Sheets("Renuzit Actuals").Range("F3:F500").Value = Sheets("Renuzit Lookup").Range("F1:F498").Value

        c = Sheets("Renuzit Actuals").Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
        Sheets("Renuzit Actuals").Cells(3, c).Resize(498).Value = Sheets("Renuzit Lookup").Range("F1:F498").Value

        Sheets("Snuggle Actuals").Range("F3:F500").Value = Sheets("Snuggle Lookup").Range("F1:F498").Value

        c = Sheets("Snuggle Actuals").Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
        Sheets("Snuggle Actuals").Cells(3, c).Resize(498).Value = Sheets("Snuggle Lookup").Range("F1:F498").Value

        Sheets("Sun Cuddle Soft Actuals").Range("F3:F500").Value = Sheets("Sun Cuddle Soft Lookup").Range("F1:F498").Value

        c = Sheets("Sun Cuddle Soft Actuals").Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
        Sheets("Sun Cuddle Soft Actuals").Cells(3, c).Resize(498).Value = Sheets("Sun Cuddle Soft Lookup").Range("F1:F498").Value

        Sheets("Sun Actuals").Range("F3:F500").Value = Sheets("Sun Lookup").Range("F1:F498").Value

        c = Sheets("Sun Actuals").Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
        Sheets("Sun Actuals").Cells(3, c).Resize(498).Value = Sheets("Sun Lookup").Range("F1:F498").Value

        Sheets("Surf Actuals").Range("F3:F500").Value = Sheets("Surf Lookup").Range("F1:F498").Value

        c = Sheets("Surf Actuals").Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
        Sheets("Surf Actuals").Cells(3, c).Resize(498).Value = Sheets("Surf Lookup").Range("F1:F498").Value

        Sheets("Uno Dos Tres Actuals").Range("F3:F500").Value = Sheets("Uno Dos Tres Lookup").Range("F1:F498").Value

        c = Sheets("Uno Dos Tres Actuals").Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
        Sheets("Uno Dos Tres Actuals").Cells(3, c).Resize(498).Value = Sheets("Uno Dos Tres Lookup").Range("F1:F498").Value
    End Sub
```

And here is a picture of what happens after I have run the macro 3 times:

<sup>(Click image for full version.)</sup>
[image: screenshot (edited by ashleedawg)]

Comment: ***Welcome to Stack Overflow!***  Just to understand, is the number a `Year+Week#` and you want to insert a new column each week?  What's the *short* version of what's wrong?  Just the formatting?  (Also FYI, *that's* why new users can't post images.  :-)  I edited it to make it legible and focus more on the important part, but the other one is still available by clicking.)

Comment: Thanks Ashlee. Yes, it is a year+week#, and I want to insert a new column each week, on a separate tab. (for 10 different brands) The issue is that the pasting appears to be random. It doesn't copy into blank column to the right, each time. It copies 2 at a time, then backwards. I just want to build out a 'database' to the right, saving down each week. Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that I was doubling the work. When I eliminated the duplicate, the macro worked great. Here is the final result:

```
Sub ActualsAutomation()
'
' ActualsAutomation Macro
'

'
    Application.Run "PERSONAL.XLSB!AllSheets"

    Dim c As Long

    c = Sheets("SS Actuals").Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
    Sheets("SS Actuals").Cells(3, c).Resize(498).Value = Sheets("SS Lookup").Range("F1:F498").Value

    c = Sheets("All Actuals").Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
    Sheets("All Actuals").Cells(3, c).Resize(498).Value = Sheets("All Lookup").Range("F1:F498").Value

    c = Sheets("Base Specialties Actuals").Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
    Sheets("Base Specialties Actuals").Cells(3, c).Resize(498).Value = Sheets("Base Specialties Lookup").Range("F1:F498").Value

    c = Sheets("Combat Actuals").Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
    Sheets("Combat Actuals").Cells(3, c).Resize(498).Value = Sheets("Combat Lookup").Range("F1:F498").Value

    c = Sheets("Great Value Actuals").Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
    Sheets("Great Value Actuals").Cells(3, c).Resize(498).Value = Sheets("Great Value Lookup").Range("F1:F498").Value

    c = Sheets("Persil Actuals").Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
    Sheets("Persil Actuals").Cells(3, c).Resize(498).Value = Sheets("Persil Lookup").Range("F1:F498").Value

    c = Sheets("Purex Actuals").Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
    Sheets("Purex Actuals").Cells(3, c).Resize(498).Value = Sheets("Purex Lookup").Range("F1:F498").Value

    c = Sheets("Renuzit Actuals").Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
    Sheets("Renuzit Actuals").Cells(3, c).Resize(498).Value = Sheets("Renuzit Lookup").Range("F1:F498").Value

    c = Sheets("Snuggle Actuals").Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
    Sheets("Snuggle Actuals").Cells(3, c).Resize(498).Value = Sheets("Snuggle Lookup").Range("F1:F498").Value

    c = Sheets("Sun Cuddle Soft Actuals").Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
    Sheets("Sun Cuddle Soft Actuals").Cells(3, c).Resize(498).Value = Sheets("Sun Cuddle Soft Lookup").Range("F1:F498").Value

    c = Sheets("Sun Actuals").Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
    Sheets("Sun Actuals").Cells(3, c).Resize(498).Value = Sheets("Sun Lookup").Range("F1:F498").Value

    c = Sheets("Surf Actuals").Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
    Sheets("Surf Actuals").Cells(3, c).Resize(498).Value = Sheets("Surf Lookup").Range("F1:F498").Value

    c = Sheets("Uno Dos Tres Actuals").Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
    Sheets("Uno Dos Tres Actuals").Cells(3, c).Resize(498).Value = Sheets("Uno Dos Tres Lookup").Range("F1:F498").Value
End Sub
```

Thanks for your help!